# Load Scraped Table via BS4 into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab any of the Basic Box Score Stat or Advanced Box Score Stats tables from [here](http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200112100LAC.html)

I tried doing something like this:

```
url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200112100LAC.html"
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html5lib")

table =  soup.find('div', class_='overthrow table_container').find('table',class_='sortable stats_table')
df = pd.read_html(table)
print df
```

However it doesnt work because of a NoneType' object error.  Is there a better way to go about taking a table code and putting it into a dataframe?  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) which return list of `DataFrame`s from all parsed tables:

```
df = pd.read_html('http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/200112100LAC.html')[0] # or [1], [2]
print (df)
```

Comment: Since this is not exactly the answer of the question, I want to mention the answer of InnocentBystander, which gives the correct answer when you already found the right table by the class:

`df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]`

Answer (score 10):

`table` is tag object in BeautifulSoup, you should transform it to string and pass it to pandas

The `prettify()` method will turn a Beautiful Soup parse tree into a nicely formatted Unicode string, with each HTML/XML tag on its own
line:

```
df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())
```

Comment: This gives a list but since OP already found the right table by class, put it into a df like this: `df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]`

Answer (score 0):

to directly pass soup in pd.read_html() use:

```
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
```

here driver is a webdriver(chrome in my case)
link open within webdriver will be passed to pandas  pd.read_html()